# Setting email priority with SPUtility.SendEmail()

Tags: email

I want to set the mail priority using `SPUtility.SendMail()`

I know I can do it with

```
MailMessage myMail = new MailMessage();
myMail.From = "from@microsoft.com";
myMail.To = "to@microsoft.com";
myMail.Subject = "UtilMailMessage001";
myMail.Priority = MailPriority.Low;
```

But my data center folks want me to use `SPUtility.SendMail()`.  Is it possbile to set the priority with `SPUtility.SendMail()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have not had an opportunity to try this, but there is a constructor of SPUtility.SendEmail which accepts a StringDictionary of MessageHeaders.

According to [this](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/p/p_471.asp) link, these are the 3 headers Microsoft uses to create a high priority email.

```
X-Priority: 1 (Highest)
X-MSMail-Priority: High
Importance: High
```

So to use it with SPUtility.SendEmail, use this code to create the headers.

```
StringDictionary messageHeaders = new StringDictionary();
messageHeaders.Add("X-Priority", "1 (Highest)");
messageHeaders.Add("X-MSMail-Priority", "High");
messageHeaders.Add("Importance", "High");
```

Comment: for completness. I also added the folowing headers since they were no longer parameters              messageHeader.Add("to", MySettings.Instance.ToAddress);
            messageHeader.Add("from", "sharepoint@test.com");
            messageHeader.Add("subject", "subject");
            messageHeader.Add("content-type", "text/html");

Answer (score 0):

No, there is nothing in the function to specify email priority.  You would need to use the .NET mail functions that you mentioned in your post.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms463202.aspx for all the available options on that function.

Comment: @john_Chapman You're saying there's NO way to send those headers using JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
StringDictionary messageHeaders = new StringDictionary();
messageHeaders.Add("X-Priority", "1 (Highest)");
messageHeaders.Add("X-MSMail-Priority", "High");
messageHeaders.Add("Importance", "High");
```

with

```
 SPUtility.SendEmail(elevetedweb, headers, strMessage.ToString());
```

This sends email marked as high-priority

Answer (score 0):

Working solution in SharePoint CSOM

```
    using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(Constants.SPSiteURL))
{
   EmailProperties email = new EmailProperties();
   email.To = toEmail;
   email.Subject = String.Format(subject);
   email.Body = body;
   email.AdditionalHeaders = new Dictionary<string, string>() 
   {
       {"X-Priority", "1 (Highest)"},
       {"X-MSMail-Priority", "High"},
       {"Importance", "High"}
   };

   Utility.SendEmail(clientContext, email);
   clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
   flag = true;
}
```